# VS Code Java Project packages issue

Tags: java, class, visual-studio-code, package

I have a small bug when I use Java in VS Code. When you create a project using the VS Code extensions, it creates a file structure with bin and src, and in the src folder there is a package called app.

Everything works correctly if I create class files in the folder: Menu, Game and GameObject, thus:

// GameObject.java

```
package app;

public abstract class GameObject {

    public abstract void draw();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Player player = new Player();
        player.draw();
    }

}
```

// Player.java

```
package app;

public class Player extends GameObject {

    @Override
    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Player");
    }
}
```

// Menu.java

```
package app;

public class Menu extends GameObject {

    @Override
    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("Menu");
    }
}
```

However, if I move these files into a package called 'game' within the app package, and then change the package statements to "package app.game;", the code doesn't compile.

My question is - why? Do I need to somehow explicitly reference the classes are if they are contained within a package of their own? Any help or explanation would be appreciated. My guess is that it's to do with the way VS Code is compiling Java.

Comment: What´s the error Message?

Comment: Cannot find symbol Player

Comment: I just tried your Code with InteliJ and Eclipse. So I think you should Check the Settings of your VS Code Plugin.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll give it a try. Appreciate the help

Comment: you could try to press `F1` ,input `clean` then select `Java:clean the  Java language workspac`, then run it.

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! I'm not sure what went wrong in the first place...